# Binary Heap Height

Tags: algorithm, heap, asymptotic-complexity, binary-heap

In a Binary Heap with `N` nodes and a height of `h`:

```
1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + … + 2^(h-1) + 1 <= N <= 1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + … + 2^(h-1) + 2^h 
2^h <= N < 2^(h+1)
h  <= log2(N)  <  h+1
```

**In the last line:**
The first inequality implies that `h` is `O(log N)`.
But how come that the second second inequality implies that `h` is `Ω(log N)` ?
If it was "`log2(N)  <  h`", I would understand it, but my problem is with the "`1`" in "`h+1`".

Comment: Yes, I know. I edited my question to highlight that I'm only interested in the last line of the three lines.

Comment: So in summary, your question is "why does `h  <= log2(N)  <  h+1` imply that `h` is `Ω(log N)` and not just that it is `O(log N)`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second inequality, you have that

*h + 1 > log(N) ↠ h > log(N) - 1*,

Therefore,

*h  = Ω(log(N) - 1)*.

However,

*log(N) - 1 = Θ(log(N))*,

and you can use the transitive rule that

*f(N) = Ω(g(N))* and *g(N) = Θ(h(N))* implies that *f(N) = Ω(h(N))*.